# Laravel's localization on JavaScript Variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-localization

I have some JavaScript variables that I output on a rating scale as shown below.

I now want to achieve Laravel's localization therefore translate the variables before outputting them on the browser.

How can I achieve this? I tried as below but it does not get converted.

```
var ratingScale = {1: 'Terrible, 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Average', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Excellent'};
```

I would want to Localize the variables  `Terrible`, `Poor`, `Average`, `Good`, and `Excellent`.

I tried this

```
var one = "<?php echo trans('form.one'); ?>";

var ratingScale = {1: one, 2: 'Poor', 3: 'Average', 4: 'Good', 5: 'Excellent'};
```

But on the browser this is outputted `<?php echo trans('form.one'); ?>`

Anyone lead me here?

Comment: in which file you are writing this js code ? .js or .php ?

Comment: @joy It's on an external JS file

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a litteral string containing that. What you probably Would like to do is output the translations as json or data-attributes somewhere in the DOM. Then pick up these variables with JavaScript.

**JSON in DOM**

In your blade output json_encoded the translations, inside script tags.

e.g. example.blade.php

```
<script>
    var ratingScale = {!! $ratingScale !!}
</script>
```

**data attribute**

output the strings as data attributes in some html element

e.g. example.blade.php

```
<form data-scale1="{{ratingScale[1]}}">
```

etc.

**call via xhr / ajax to the server**

```
 axios.get('/ratingScales');
```

Create an extra endpoint to retrieve these translations as json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code it will work if you are in blade file.(you can move you js code in blade file and try this also it will work)

```
var one = {{ trans('form.one') }};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to include such javascript file in my blade templates like always:

```
@extends('adminlte::layouts.app')

@section('htmlheader_title')
Viajes en curso
@stop

@section('links')
@include('zendesk.widget')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/app_adminlte_custom.css') }}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/app/trips.js') !!}"></script>
    @stop

    @section('notifications_menu')
    @include('app.partials.notifications_menu')
    @stop
    ........ big etc ....
```

But, at some point I initialize the variables I need from this blade file itself:

```
@section('extra-js')

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTranslatedTitle = {{ trans('whatever') }};
    var numAcceptedTrips = {{ $numAcceptedTrips }};
</script>

@yield('extra-js')
```

Just bear in mind these variables are global.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package:

https://github.com/mralgorithm2000/laravel-js-lang

With this package you can use __() laravel function in JavaScript with the same syntax